# How to use a string instead of a stream?

Tags: c#, stream

I need to use this:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm

This is code to convert object to BSON format. The code which interests me is this:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
using (Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonWriter writer = new Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonWriter(stream))
{
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(writer, message);
}
```

However, I want the result in a string. So do I really have to use a stream or a file to write stuff in, then read it to put it in the string?

There must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Modify your question to summarize what the link is doing.  Don't make us go there to get the gist of what you're talking about.

Comment: BSON stands for ***Binary*** Structured Object Notation.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Not sure what you are trying to say?

Comment: So have you tried any other *better* way?

Comment: @VladimirNul I did what is in the answer accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the *string* from the *stream* using `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`:

```
        string bsonText = "";

        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (BsonWriter writer = new Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonWriter(stream))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, message);

            stream.Position = 0;
            bsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Or also, `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`:

```
        using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (BsonWriter writer = new Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonWriter(stream))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, message);

            bsonText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
```

BTW who knows what you're going to get from this, since *BSON* is a binary object representation, it's not like JSON!